# Monty Hall implementation

Tags: c, random, probability

I recently watched a video regarding the Monty Hall problem and found it interesting, so I thought of implementing it to see if the probability is truly 66.6% as predicted.

Here is what I have,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int repeat = 5000000, i;
    int win = 0, lose = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= repeat; i++) {
        int winDoor = rand();
        winDoor = winDoor % 4;

        int firstPick = rand();
        firstPick = firstPick % 4;

        if (winDoor == firstPick) {
            lose++;
        } else {
            win++;
        }
    }

    printf("%.2f percent win rate\n", ((float)win/(float)repeat)*100.00);
}
```

However, I seem to be getting a 75% win rate (by switching doors) with the above code. Is there something wrong with my codes? Or is the 66.6% (2/3) a lie?

P.S. The logic I implemented is, if winning door is first picked, by switching, we lose. If losing door is first picked, by switching, we win. That's how I understand the Monty Hall problem.

EDIT: I actually put %4 because I read that %4 will represent 0-3. I forgot I need 1-3, not 0-3. Question resolved.

Comment: Only true for 3 doors, but you seem to use 4 `winDoor % 4`. With four doors you can even pick a loosing door again if at first you already did.

Comment: This doesn't actually emulate the monty hall problem, the mathematical crux of the problem lies in the Dealer opening a remaining door and the player choosing to switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you're using `% 4` instead of `% 3`. That simulates 4 doors instead of 3, so the result changes from `2/3` to `3/4`.

Comment: Does not explain the 75% chance, which is wrongly calculated. With more than three doors the chance is lower than 2/3, not higher. And is actually wrong if with 3/4 you mean the winning chance when switching.

Comment: @Yunnosch The chance does go up with more doors if you always switch, assuming that all but two doors are revealed after the initial selection. (Try it with 100 doors and you'll have a 99% chance of winning.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks for that interesting information. I was thinking that no  showmaster would offer that...

Answer (score 2):

You're choosing from 4 doors, not 3. change your %4 to a %3.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int repeat = 5000000, i;
    int win = 0, lose = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= repeat; i++) {
        int winDoor = rand();
        winDoor = winDoor % 3;

        int firstPick = rand();
        firstPick = firstPick % 3;

        if (winDoor == firstPick) {
            lose++;
        } else {
            win++;
        }
    }

    printf("%.2f percent win rate\n", ((float)win/(float)repeat)*100.00);
}
```

Comment: No worries, everyone makes mistakes :) Glad to help!